# Every Laravel route (even 127.0.0.1:8000/asdasdasdsas) is redirecting to the homepage

Tags: laravel, routes

Every route is redirecting to the homepage. Here are my routes:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'index'])->name('main');
Route::get('/contact', [MainController::class, 'contact'])->name('contact');
Route::get('/imprint', [MainController::class, 'imprint'])->name('imprint');
Route::get('/privacy', [MainController::class, 'privacy'])->name('privacy');
Route::get('/terms', [MainController::class, 'terms'])->name('terms');
Route::get('/withdrawal', [MainController::class, 'withdrawal'])->name('withdrawal');
Route::post('/contact-post', [MainController::class, 'contactSend'])->name('post.contact');
Route::get('/apply-now', [MainController::class, 'apply'])->name('apply');
Route::get('/apply-now-login', [MainController::class, 'applyLogin'])->name('apply.login');
Route::post('/save-request', [MainController::class, 'saveRequest'])->name('save.request');
Route::get('/dashboard', [MainController::class, 'applications'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
Route::post('/updateApplication/{id}', [MainController::class, 'updateApplication'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('application.update');
Route::post('/deleteApplication/{id}', [MainController::class, 'deleteApplication'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('application.delete');
Route::post('/verifyPayment/{id}', [MainController::class, 'verifyPayment'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('verify.payment');
Route::post('/verifyPaypalPayment', [MainController::class, 'updatePaypalPayment'])->name('verify.paypal');
Route::post('/verifyPaypalAuth', [MainController::class, 'updatePaypalPaymentForAuthUser'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('verify.paypal.auth');
Route::post('/uploadFiles/{id}', [MainController::class, 'uploadFiles'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('application.upload');
Route::post('/reopen-application', [MainController::class, 'reopenApplication'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('reopen.app');
Route::get('/preview-pdf/{filename}', [MainController::class, 'checkFileAccess'])->name('preview.result');
require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
```

Comment: Can you share your MainController as a code snippet? Maybe you are returning view wrong

Answer (score 0):

//Nothing wrong with the controller checked it over 50 times.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('main');
}

public function apply()
{
    return view('apply-form');
}

public function applyLogin()
{
    return view('apply-form-login');
}

public function contact()
{
    return view('contact');
}

public function imprint()
{
    return view('imprint');
}

public function privacy()
{
    return view('privacy');
}

public function terms()
{
    return view('terms');
}

public function withdrawal()
{
    return view('withdrawal');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).